# NgBootstrap's ngbPopover doesn't work when used within an ng-container

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

When placing the default example popover from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples) in a table, it works within tbody and tr but once I want to add it within the td it doesn't show, even if I append it to the body using `container="body"`

**Popover code:**

```
 <button
    type="button"
    class="btn btn-outline-secondary me-2"
    placement="top"
    ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
    popoverTitle="Popover on top"
  ></button>
```

**HTML:**

```
 <tbody>
    
    <tr *ngFor="let subtask of item.subtasks; let i=index">
 
        <td 
          *ngFor="let subtaskItem of getSubtaskItems(subtask); let j=index"
          [attr.colspan] = "subtaskItem.duration"
          [ngClass]="getCellClass(subtask, subtaskItem)"
         >
```

Comment: Would wrapping the button within a div element inside the td help?

Comment: please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jj4sm-59qa9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-customclass.html

Comment: @VonC no, wrapping the button inside a div within the td yields the same result

Comment: The cruicial difference in my example is the source of the arrays of the ngFor. In case of the TR, it comes from a variable. In case of the TD it comes from a controller function. This shall not make any difference in the bindings, however it seems to do in the case of the ngbPopover.

Comment: @cfprabhu thanks, I have modified yours to show the problem in vitro. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jj4sm-umu8ws?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-customclass.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-customclass.ts

Answer (score 0):

while inspecting a single popOver it have an attribute `aria-describedby="ngb-popover-0"`, which may be a problem in your code, you should try to add it as unique with looping index or something and hopefully it will work.

also inspect the id of the popover window and it should be unique

Hope it Helps..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a function in the loop

When you have a function in .html, when you click a button, Angular need call to the function. As you function return a new array each time, Angular repaint your table and the "tooltip disappear".

The solution is use a variable

```
  subTaskItems=this.getSubtaskItems()

<td *ngFor="let subtaskItem of subTaskItems; let j=index">
  ...
</td>
```

your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4jj4sm-rsthmk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-customclass.html,src%2Fapp%2Fpopover-customclass.ts)

Well, you have two loops. The better options is that the inner loop was a property of the first one. Some like

```
    tasks=[{id:1,name:'one',subTasks:[{id:11,name:'one one'},{id:12,name:'one two'},
           {id:2,name:'two',subTasks:[{id:21,name:'two one'},{id:22,name:'two two'},
           ...
          ]

<div *ngFor="let task of taks">
    ...
    <div *ngFor="let subtask of task.subTasks">
          ...
    </div>
</div>
```

If you received the task from an API in a different way, try transform the data you receive in an array like shown above

```
tasks=dataReceived.map(x=>({...x,subTask:this.getSubtaskItems(x)})
```